# pandas : Unable to update empty dataframe by single string

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I created an empty dataframe and tried adding one string value to a column but it is showing empty

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['Man'] = "manish"
print(df)
```

when i am running above code i am getting output as:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Man]
Index: []
```

---

While when i am running below code

```
df['Man'] = ['manish']
print(df)
```

i am getting correct output which i expected

```
      Man
0  manish
```

Can anyone explain me why this is happening ?

Comment: This `df['Man'] == "manish"` is comparison.

Comment: You should have got an error with the first snippet. `==` (two equal signs) is a test for equality. `=` is an assign (this is what you want here)

Comment: Probably because the index is empty

Comment: The first case broadcasts the value across the row index. As the index is empty it adds no values, but adds the key to the column index. In the second case, by specifying `[]` you indicate there's a length of 1. IMO it's odd that `pandas` allows this to work because `len(df) == 0` and `len(['manish']) == 1`. In all cases where the index has a positive size and they mismatch you'd receive `ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index`

Comment: Sorry `df['Man'] == "manish"` i added by mistake , even with `df['Man'] = "manish"` same issue persists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems, by looking at the code of `__setitem__` that it expects a *list like value*, as written in the function `_ensure_valid_index`:

```
def _ensure_valid_index(self, value):
    """
    Ensure that if we don't have an index, that we can create one from the
    passed value.
    """
    # GH5632, make sure that we are a Series convertible
    if not len(self.index) and is_list_like(value):
        try:
            value = Series(value)
        except (ValueError, NotImplementedError, TypeError):
            raise ValueError(
                "Cannot set a frame with no defined index "
                "and a value that cannot be converted to a "
                "Series"
            )

        self._data = self._data.reindex_axis(
            value.index.copy(), axis=1, fill_value=np.nan
        )
```

So if the len of the index is zero (as in your case) it expects a list like value, which a string is not, to convert to a Series an use the index from there. The function `_ensure_valid_index` is called inside `set_item`.